# custom XML serialization in Java with JAXB

Tags: java, xml, serialization, jaxb

My problem is the following:

I have an object structure with one root class and  a lot of sub-classes. These classes are generated from xsd files and I cannot change them.

One of the classes (not the root class) looks approximately like this:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "Foo")
class Foo {
    @XmlAnyElement(lax = true)
    Object any;
}
```

I know that there is only about five classes (BarOne, ..., BarFive), that 'any' can be set to.

So the xml looks like this:

```
<RootClass>
lots of stuff...
    <foo>
        <any>
            <BarOne>
                fields and sub-classes of BarOne
            </BarOne>
        </any>
    </foo>
more stuff..
</RootClass>
```

I'm (de-)serializing with the JAXB (Un-)Marshaller and all classes have all the annotations needed for correct (de-)serialization. But when deserializing an object of class `Foo` (with 'any' != null), the Unmarshaller sets `any` to an object of JAXBElement which has, amongst others, a `value` field with the `BarOne`-object in it. This is a real problem for all operations I have to perform on `Foo` and its subclasses.

That is why I would like to implement a custom (de-)serialization for `Foo` and the `BarXXX` classes so that I get to set `any` directly to an object of a `Bar` class (which is where I would expect it when looking at the xml structure (and also the object structure)). Deserialization should work equivalently. The (de-)serialization of the `Bar`-classes and their subclasses could/should be performed by the default implementation of the (Un-)Marshaller again.

But I'm not able to figure out what exactly I need to do to accomplish that. I have already read a lot about different ways of customization and maybe it's just that I can't fit the pieces together that I need...
Does someone have an idea?

As I already mentioned, I cannot change the definition of the xsd files that all the classes are generated from. What I could do is using a bindings file when generating the classes, but I would rather solve the problem without that.

**EDIT:**
I've read about the possibility of using the `@XmlAnyElement` annotation for working on a DOM tree structure, but I'm not sure how it would work in this situation...